# find the best solution for partial rendering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I need an update panel but I don't want it to affect performance. Update panels make my web application slow, and I don't know why?

Is update panel dangerous, and how I can fix my problem? Is there any good solution for partial rendering?

Comment: It's been asked a good number of times across the web. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151821/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-ajax-update-panels-in-asp-net-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great article here: [UpdatePanel Tips and Tricks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx) which illustrates some of the pitfalls and ways to use it better.

I loathe the ACToolkit. [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) is easy to use and fast. A much better solution IMO.